# how to expend array values in rows!! using Hive SQL

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a table with 4 columns, one column (items) type is ARRAY and other are string.

```
ID   |    items                                  | name  |  loc  
_________________________________________________________________

id1  | ["item1","item2","item3","item4","item5"] | Mike | CT
id2  | ["item3","item7","item4","item9","item8"] | Chris| MN
.
.
```

Here, I want unnormalized output like

```
ID   |    items                       | name  |  loc  
______________________________________________________
id1  | item1                          | Mike  | CT
id1  | item2                          | Mike  | CT
id1  | item3                          | Mike  | CT
id1  | item4                          | Mike  | CT
id1  | item5                          | Mike  | CT
id2  | item3                          | Chris | MN
id2  | item7                          | Chris | MN
id2  | item4                          | Chris | MN
id2  | item9                          | Chris | MN
id2  | item8                          | Chris | MN
```

I am not a Hive SQL expert, Please help me out of this.

Comment: look at "explode" function in hive : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-explode

Comment: Select explode(items) is working for one field only, how to fetch other columns with explode?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT ID,itemsName,name,loc
 FROM Table
 LATERAL VIEW explode(items) itemTable AS itemsName;
```

in explode(items) , there items is your stored table column and Table is your Stored table.

Comment: Hi Kishore,

Thanks for your reply. can we do the same with multiple array type columns?

like

ID | items | item_Name | name | loc
                                                              
____________________________________________________________________
id1 | ["item1","item2","item3","item4","item5"] |  ["Ruler","Cap","Pen","brush
","Eraser"] | Mike | CT

id2 | ["item3","item7","item4","item9","item8"] |  ["Pen","Pencil","brush"," ","Calc"] | Chris| MN

Comment: I am not getting your problem, make as another question and define question properly.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `posexplode()` function to achieve the scenario you mentioned, that is with multiple array columns.

Something like this will work out:

```sql
SELECT ID,i1.item,i2.itemName,name,loc
 FROM Table
 LATERAL VIEW posexplode(items) i1 AS item,item_1
 LATERAL VIEW posexplode(item_Name) i2 AS itemName,itemName_1
 WHERE item=itemName
```