# Parse XML in Hive

Tags: xml, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have the below nested xml which I have to parse as table in hive.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animals>
    <animals_data key="72" Value="LD3" />
    <Lions>
        <Lion key="false" Value="abc">
            <Tigers>
                <Tiger key="false" Value="1">
                    <Tiger_details key="6" Value="asdsa" />
                    <Tiger_details key="7" Value="adas" />
                    <Tiger_details key="8" Value="adsa" />
                    <Tiger_details key="9" Value="adas" />
                    <Cats>
                        <Cat key="false" Value="sds">
                            <cat_details key="18" Value="jhgj" />
                            <cat_details key="19" Value="jhjhg" />
                            <Pubs>
                                <Pub key="false" Value="1">
                                    <Pub_details key="24" Value="6" />
                                    <Pub_details key="25" Value="43" />
                                    <Dogs>
                                        <D key="false" Value="1">
                                            <D_d key="35" Value="4" />
                                            <D_d key="36" Value="4" />
                                        </D><D k="false" v="2">
                                            <D_d key="35" Value="4" />
                                            <D_d key="36" Value="5" />
                                        </D>
                                    </Dogs>
                                </Pub>
                            </Pubs>
                        </Cat>
                        <Cat key="false" Value="lko">
                            <cat_details key="18" Value="fgf" />
                            <cat_details key="19" Value="gfgf" />
                        <Pubs>
                                <Pub key="false" Value="1">
                                    <Pub_details key="27" Value="54" />
                                    <Pub_details key="48" Value="554" />
                                    <Dogs>
                                        <D key="false" Value="1">
                                            <D_d key="68" Value="9" />
                                            <D_d key="69" Value="2" />
                                        </D>
                                    </Dogs>
                                </Pub>
                                <Pub key="false" Value="2">
                                    <Pub_details key="27" Value="7" />
                                    <Dogs>
                                        <D key="false" Value="1">
                                            <D_d key="68" Value="92" />
                                            <D_d key="69" Value="21" />
                                        </D>
                                    </Dogs>
                                </Pub>
                            </Pubs>
                        </Cat>
                    </Cats>
                </Tiger>
            </Tigers>
        </Lion>
    </Lions>
</animals>
```

I checked the following stackoverflow post [Exception while using lateral view in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41481582/exception-while-using-lateral-view-in-hive)

The xml format in the post differs from what I have. How can I parse this xml using the xml serde mentioned in the said post or using any other method.

**EDIT: XPATH QUERY**

```
SELECT 
xpath(xmls,'/animals/animals_data/@key') AS animals_data_key,
xpath(xmls,"/animals/animals_data/@Value")  AS animals_data_value,
xpath(xmls,"/animals/Lions/Lion/@key") AS lion_key,
xpath(xmls,"/animals/Lions/Lion/@Value") AS lion_value,
xpath(xmls,"/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/@key") AS tiger_key,
xpath(xmls,"/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/@Value") AS tiger_value,
xpath(xmls,"/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/Tiger_details/@key") AS tiger_details_key,
xpath(xmls,"/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/Tiger_details/@Value") AS tiger_details_value,
xpath(xmls,"/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/Cats/Cat/@key") AS cat_key,
xpath(xmls,"/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/Cats/Cat/@Value") AS cat_value,
xpath(xmls,"/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/Cats/Cat/cat_details/@key") as cat_details_key,
xpath(xmls,"/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/Cats/Cat/cat_details/@Value") AS cat_details_value,
xpath(xmls,"/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/Cats/Cat/Pubs/Pub/@key") AS pubs_key,
xpath(xmls,"/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/Cats/Cat/Pubs/Pub/@Value") AS pubs_value,
xpath(xmls,"/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/Cats/Cat/Pubs/Pub/Pub_details/@key") AS pub_details_key,
xpath(xmls,"/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/Cats/Cat/Pubs/Pub/Pub_details/@Value") AS pub_details_value,
xpath(xmls,"/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/Cats/Cat/Pubs/Pub/Dogs/D/@key") AS d_key,
xpath(xmls,"/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/Cats/Cat/Pubs/Pub/Dogs/D/@Value") as d_value,
xpath(xmls,"/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/Cats/Cat/Pubs/Pub/Dogs/D/D_d/@key") AS dd_key,
xpath(xmls,"/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/Cats/Cat/Pubs/Pub/Dogs/D/D_d/@Value") AS dd_value
FROM xmldata;
```

[image: XPATH Output]

**Serde Query**

```
add jar adl://aoadls.azuredatalakestore.net/cluster/hadoop/xmlserde/hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar;

DROP TABLE IF exists sample3;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE sample3(
animals_data_key ARRAY<STRING>,
animals_data_value ARRAY<STRING>,
lion_key ARRAY<STRING>,
lion_value ARRAY<STRING>,
tiger_key ARRAY<STRING>,
tiger_value ARRAY<STRING>,
tiger_details_key ARRAY<STRING>,
tiger_details_value ARRAY<STRING>,
cat_key ARRAY<STRING>,
cat_value ARRAY<STRING>,
cat_details_key ARRAY<STRING>,
cat_details_value ARRAY<STRING>,
pub_key ARRAY<STRING>,
pub_value ARRAY<STRING>,
pub_details_key ARRAY<STRING>,
pub_details_value ARRAY<STRING>,
d_key ARRAY<STRING>,
d_value ARRAY<STRING>,
dd_k ARRAY<STRING>,
dd_v ARRAY<STRING>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"column.xpath.animals_data_key"="/animals/animals_data/@key",
"column.xpath.animals_data_value"="/animals/animals_data/@Value",
"column.xpath.lion_key"="/animals/Lions/Lion/@key",
"column.xpath.lion_value"="/animals/Lions/Lion/@Value",
"column.xpath.tiger_key"="/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/@key",
"column.xpath.tiger_value"="/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/@Value",
"column.xpath.tiger_details_key"="/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/Tiger_details/@key",
"column.xpath.tiger_details_value"="/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/Tiger_details/@Value",
"column.xpath.cat_key"="/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/Cats/Cat/@key",
"column.xpath.cat_value"="/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/Cats/Cat/@Value",
"column.xpath.cat_details_key"="/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/Cats/Cat/cat_details/@key",
"column.xpath.cat_details_value"="/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/Cats/Cat/cat_details/@Value",
"column.xpath.pub_key"="/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/Cats/Cat/Pubs/Pub/@key",
"column.xpath.pub_value"="/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/Cats/Cat/Pubs/Pub/@Value",
"column.xpath.pub_details_key"="/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/Cats/Cat/Pubs/Pub/Pub_details/@key",
"column.xpath.pub_details_value"="/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/Cats/Cat/Pubs/Pub/Pub_details/@Value",
"column.xpath.d_key"="/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/Cats/Cat/Pubs/Pub/Dogs/D/@key",
"column.xpath.d_value"="/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/Cats/Cat/Pubs/Pub/Dogs/D/@Value",
"column.xpath.dd_k"="/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/Cats/Cat/Pubs/Pub/Dogs/D/D_d/@key",
"column.xpath.dd_v"="/animals/Lions/Lion/Tigers/Tiger/Cats/Cat/Pubs/Pub/Dogs/D/D_d/@Value"
)
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION '/samplexml/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
"xmlinput.start"="<animals>",
"xmlinput.end"="</animals>"
);
```

I have attached the corresponding output as well. How can I expand the output to multiple rows instead of single row.

[image: SerDe output]

**Select Query**

```
add jar adl://aoadls.azuredatalakestore.net/cluster/hadoop/xmlserde/hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar;

--SELECT * FROM sample3;

SELECT 
    adk.adkvalue AS animals_data_key,
    adl.adlvalue AS animals_data_value,
    lk.lkvalue AS lion_key,
    lv.lvvalue AS lion_value,
    tk.tkvalue AS tiger_key,
    tv.tvvalue AS tiger_value,
    tdk.tdkvalue AS tiger_details_key,
    tdv.tdvvalue AS tiger_details_value,
    ck.ckvalue AS cat_key,
    cv.cvvalue AS cat_value,
    cdk.cdkvalue AS cat_details_key,
    cdv.cdvvalue AS cat_details_value,
    pk.pkvalue AS pub_key,
    pv.pvvalue AS pub_value,
    pdk.pdkvalue AS pub_details_key
    --pdv.pdvvalue AS pub_details_value
from sample3
LATERAL VIEW explode(animals_data_key) adk as adkvalue
LATERAL VIEW explode(animals_data_value) adl as adlvalue
LATERAL VIEW explode(lion_key) lk as lkvalue
LATERAL VIEW explode(lion_value) lv as lvvalue
LATERAL VIEW explode(tiger_key) tk as tkvalue
LATERAL VIEW explode(tiger_value) tv as tvvalue
LATERAL VIEW explode(tiger_details_key) tdk as tdkvalue
LATERAL VIEW explode(tiger_details_value) tdv as tdvvalue
LATERAL VIEW explode(cat_key) ck as ckvalue
LATERAL VIEW explode(cat_value) cv as cvvalue
LATERAL VIEW explode(cat_details_key) cdk as cdkvalue
LATERAL VIEW explode(cat_details_value) cdv as cdvvalue
LATERAL VIEW explode(pub_key) pk as pkvalue
LATERAL VIEW explode(pub_value) pv as pvvalue
LATERAL VIEW explode(pub_details_key) pdk as pdkvalue
```

**Select Query Output**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMWhk.jpg

Comment: You figure out the XPath for your respective data

Comment: @cricket_007 modified the post. I am getting the correct result, however, how can I get the output in different rows.

Comment: Can you edit the post to show how you expect the data to be in many rows? As far as your Xml goes, there's only one `Lions` tag within the `animals` element, so you only get one row...

Comment: I don't know how this xml was generated, but a Tiger is not a type of Lion. Those are different Cats, so the outer element of both would be `Cats`. Neither one is a Dog, and it's unclear what D or Pub are supposed to mean... Also XML is not only limited to attributes of Key/Value or K/V

Comment: I want to expand arrays as shown in the output in table format.

Comment: All of your columns of your hive table are defined as strings. You need to define some of them as array type... https://github.com/dvasilen/Hive-XML-SerDe/wiki/XML-data-sources#3-arrays 
   Again, though, since there's only one Lions tag within the `xmlinput.start` treat you've specified, you only get "one row". Hive however is not limited to only store primitive values in rows

Comment: I changed the data type of all columns to array and I am now getting all values in array format in single row. Only thing I want is how to explode multiple array columns so as to avoid Cartesian product.

Comment: As explained, if you add another pair of `<Lions></Lions>` tags within the `<animals></animals>` element, then you will get multiple rows. In other words, you need to re-order your XML if you are expecting to have many rows of data.

Comment: Or you can learn to use [`LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039799/how-to-expend-array-values-in-rows-using-hive-sql)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148244/discussion-between-ahmad-osama-and-cricket-007).